# Замена DOM элемента в jquery

Tags: jquery

Кто-нибудь сможет на пальцах и на примере кода объяснить как заменить один dom-элемент на другой.

Есть код:

```
<td id="18"><div class="label"></div> текст</td>
<td id="22"><div class="label"></div> тут тоже текст</td>

<div class="pp">
<div class="label" id="3"></div>
<div class="label" id="4"></div>
</div>
```

По клику на **div.label** всплывает **div.pp**, при клике по одному из div'ов внутри **div.pp** этот div должен заменить div внутри ячейки td, по клику на которой вызывался **div.pp**. Замена должна произойти клонированием - это раз, и заменить нужно не текст внутри **div.label** а сам объект.

Никак не догоню как это делается. Может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

Comment: да-да, я уже разобрался, так всегда, пару часов мучаюсь над проблемой, пишу сюда, а как только написал, так сразу нахожу решение :). Вот только другая проблема появилась. После замены, клик на замененном элементе уже не вызывает **div.pp** . Только я cделал с помощью replaceAll(), с помощью replaceWith() что-то не получилось

Comment: Вешайте событие не `$('table .label').click(...)`, а `$('table .label').live('click', ...)`.

Comment: Да так и сделал, но что-то не получалось. Просто видимо js не хотел в кеше обновляться. Сейчас все ок, Спасибо!